# <bsd/string.h> for windows

Tags: c, string, windows

I am using strlcpy, strlcat , strtok_r functions in my c program.
When I compiled it I got

```
undefined reference to `strlcpy', undefined reference to `strlcat', undefined reference to `strtok_r'
```

I googled and found out I need to use `<bsd/string.h>` . But I found resources only for installing libbsd for linux.

Can anyone one point me on how to install bsd for windows

Comment: My recommendation is that you replace all non-portable code with code that is actually portable. And if that's not possible, then use conditional compilation to implement those functions yourself.

Comment: More if you want to run your code in windows and/or BSD systems.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for you, there's no *official* port of libbsd to Windows at this time. Your options are:

1. replace the nonstandard `strl*` functions with the standardized (but somewhat inferior) `strn*` functions (like `strncpy`, `strncat`)
2. replace the nonstandard `strl*` functions with Windows' nonstandard `_s` functions (like `strcpy_s`, `strcat_s`, `strtok_s`)
3. install the unofficial [`libbsd-minimal`](https://github.com/AltSysrq/libbsd-minimal) package which claims to work for Windows (untested)
4. build and install libbsd yourself on MinGW based on [this long-standing pull request on libbsd](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libbsd/libbsd/merge_requests/1)

In all likelihood, (2) gets you the closest (based on API similarity) but will probably require you to add some platform-specific macros or utility code in order to stay portable.